# Loop through Array in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Why does this give an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception:

```
public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array[] = new int[10];
        array[0]=34;
        array[1]=43;
        array[2]=55;
for (int i : array) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Because you're trying to print `array[34]`, `array[43]` and `array[55]` which don't exist.

Do:

```
for(int i : array) {
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

This *enhanced form* of the `for` loop does *"for each integer called `i` in the `array` do..."* rather than *"for each **index** called `i` in the `array` do..."*.

Answer (score 0):

You insert `34` as `array[0]` so when `i == array[0] == 34`, `array[i]` evaluates to `array[34]` and throws an Exception since `array` has 10 elements.

You probably want to print the content of `array`:

```
for (int i : array) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Or:

```
Arrays.stream(array).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or (different output):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because i has this values in loop 34 next loop 43 next loop 55